# webkit box orient styling disappears from styling

Tags: css, angular, ionic-framework, sass, ellipsis

In my Angular app (I'm on version 4.3.1) I'm adding a CSS ellipsis after multiple lines.
For this, I use the following css code in Sass.

```
.ellipsis {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

For some reason, the box-orient line simply gets removed from the styling by the transpile, causing the ellipsis to not work. This seems to happen in Angular and Ionic apps.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-orient is an old syntax version and requires flexbox

Comment: I know it's deprecated, but it still works when adding ellipsis on the nth line of a paragraph. And in my case, it's safe to use because all users use the same browser.

Comment: Why are there two `display` rules? Isn't enough to use `display: -webkit-box` only?

Comment: `display: block` is a fallback. A `div` has `display:block` by default, but if you were to use a span it would have `display: inline-block` by default. In this case I think I wanted to have the `display` set to `block`.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Wrapping `-webkit-box-orient` in the following autoprefixer code seems to solve the issue.

```
.ellipsis {
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    /* autoprefixer: off */
}
```

Comment: The quoted pieces of code around -webkit-box-orient are different. And they seem to make all the difference.

Comment: This also resolves the exact same problem I was having in a React app built using create-react-app

Comment: You deserve a bit of my pay !

Comment: Why are there two display rules? Isn't enough to use display: `-webkit-box` only? In addition, doesn't it work even removing `text-overflow: ellipsis`?

Comment: And... what the hell is that `autoprefixer` comment? O_o

Comment: @smartmouse OP seems to about ionic/angular app.. ionic v2/3 uses [autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#readme) in the build process

Comment: Yes, I see, it works in my case as well because I'm developing an Angular app. Thanks.

Comment: I received this warning:

**Warning
(20:3) Second Autoprefixer control comment was ignored. Autoprefixer applies control comment to whole block, not to next rules.** just one autoprefixer can be used per block!

Comment: So, this is an autoprefixer bug?

Answer (score 29):

Similar solution as was previously presented, but one less line if that's your thing:

```
.ellipsis {
    /* autoprefixer: ignore next */
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    display: block;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

The following work for me.

```
.ellipsis {
/* autoprefixer: off */
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
/* autoprefixer: on */
display: block;
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-line-clamp: 2;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

}

Comment: as per documentation second rule will get ignored - https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#control-comments

Comment: They docs linked above have this listed as how not to use these comments:

`/* How not to use block level control comments */`

Answer (score 7):

For SCSS:

```
/*! autoprefixer: ignore next */
-webkit-box-orient: vertical;
```

Comment: The `!` was not necessary for me using scss.

Comment: THIS! Took me some time to figure out that comment "!" to work.

Answer (score 5):

None of the answers worked for me.

My solution was to put the `-webkit-box-orient: vertical` as inline-styling and the rest as a class. Not elegant, but it works.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me (using scss) thanks!